# How to find the tangent line of a level curve of a function?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, tangent-line

I'm trying to solve this exercise but I'm having some issue.
Find the equation of the tangent line of $e^{x-y}(2x^2+y^2)$ at the point $(1,0)$ at the level curve.
So I start finding the gradient of the function
$gradf={e^{x-y}(2x^2+y^2)+4xe^{x-y} \choose -e^{x-y}(2x^2+y^2)+2ye^{x-y}}$
But now I don't know how to go on and even if find the gradient is actually correct, can someone help me by explaining me how to solve this excercise?

Comment: derive $f(x)=e^{x-y}(2x^2+y^2)$. When you get $f'(x)$ plug in the value $x=1$ to get a y value. That will be the gradient of the tangent to the curve $f(x)$. Then write $y=mx+b$, filling in $m$ with whatever you got for the gradient. Then plug in $(1,0)$ and solve for $b$

Comment: The title is misleading. You can't find the tangent line of a *function*, what you want is the tangent line of a *level curve* of that function (at a particular point).

Comment: @Marco  Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details [HERE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$z = f(x,y) = e^{x-y} (2x^2 + y^2).$$  Then at the point $(1,0)$, the value of $z$ is $f(1,0) = 2e$, hence the level curve is given by the implicit relation $$f(x,y) = 2e = e^{x-y}(2x^2 + y^2).$$  Then implicit differentiation gives $$0 = \left(1 - \frac{dy}{dx}\right)e^{x-y}(2x^2 + y^2) + e^{x-y} \left(4x + 2y \frac{dy}{dx}\right),$$ or $$e^{x-y} \left(2x^2 + y^2 + 4x + (-2x^2 -y^2 + 2y)\frac{dy}{dx}\right) = 0$$ or $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2x^2 + 4x + y^2}{2x^2 + y^2 - 2y}.$$  At $(x,y) = (1,0)$, we find the slope $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{6}{2} = 3$$ and the rest is trivial.

This solution is provided in order to illustrate that the concepts introduced in multivariable calculus are a natural extension of concepts from the univariate calculus; here, we treat the level set as an implicit curve--note it was not actually necessary to compute the $z$-value of that level set--and the implicit derivative computation is analogous to the gradient computation.  This relationship is not a coincidence.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Recall that

- $\nabla f(x_0,y_0)$ is perpendicular to the level curve at $(x_0,y_0)$
- then the tangent vector $v$ at $(x_0,y_0)$ is such that $$v\cdot \nabla f(x_0,y_0)=0$$
- the parametric equation for the tangent line is $(x,y)=(x_0,y_0)+tv$
- let $v=(a,b)$ with $b\neq 0$ then the cartesian equation for the tangent is

$$(y-y_0)=\frac{b}{a}(x-x_0)$$

Answer (score 0):

Your gradient looks correct to me.

Use the chain rule.  Along the level curve $f(x,y) = c$, as long as $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \neq 0$, we can consider $y$ as implicitly a function of $x$.  Then
$$
    \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dx} = 0
$$
so
$$
    \frac{dy}{dx} = - \frac{\partial f/\partial x}{\partial f/\partial y}
$$