# Find gradient and line tangent to level curve of $f(x, y)=\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}$ at $(0, 2)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I was requested  to find the line tangent to the level curve of $f(x, y)=\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}$ at $(0, 2)$ and the gradient of $f$ at the same point. The gradient is quite clearly $\triangledown f(0, 2)=<1,0>$ ("<>" denotes vectors), because

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= \frac{2y(y^2-x^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} &=  \frac{2x(x^2-y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}
\end{align}

However, I encountered a bit of a problem with the level curve. With $f(0, 2)=0$, the level curve is

$$\begin{align} \frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2} &= 0 \\ xy&=0\end{align}$$

How am I suppose to find the line tangent to this curve at$(0, 2)$? I tried to reason my way through this and noticed that  if we let $xy=0$ then $\frac{dy}{dx}(xy) = \frac{dy}{dx}0=0$ and then the line is of the form

$$t(x)= 0x+b=b$$

Because $t$ must pass through $0, 2$ we have $b=2$ and the line tangent to $f$ at the point is

$$t(x)=2$$

However this makes no sense to me, because $xy=0$ represents the vertical axis at $x=0$, while $t(x)=2$ is a horizontal line, and clearly a horizontal line can not be tangent to a point in a vertical line. How would one go about this problem?

Comment: Try referencing this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2903125/how-to-find-the-tangent-line-of-a-level-curve-of-a-function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f(0,2)=0$, that level curve is$$\left\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\,\middle|\,\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}=0\right\}=\{(x,0)\mid x\in\Bbb R\}\cup\{(0,x)\mid x\in\Bbb R\}.$$So, that tangent line that you're after is the line $\{(0,x)\mid x\in\Bbb R\}$ (that is, it's the $y$-axis).

Comment: Thank you so much.